# CSS media queries: max-width OR max-height

Tags: css, media-queries

When writing a CSS media query, is there any way you can specify multiple conditions with "OR" logic?

I'm attempting to do something like this:

```css
/* This doesn't work */
@media screen and (max-width: 995px OR max-height: 700px) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1136, accepted):

Use a comma to specify two (or more) different rules:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 995px), 
       screen and (max-height: 700px) {
  ...
}
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

> Commas are used to combine multiple media queries into a single rule. Each query in a comma-separated list is treated separately from the others. Thus, if any of the queries in a list is true, the entire media statement returns true. In other words, lists behave like a logical or operator.

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 568px) and (max-height: 320px) {} - in my case this works correct

Comment: @nosensus, the comma implies an OR relationship, meaning either may be true for the rules to apply, as per the original question. The code you show is for an AND relationship in which _both_ must be true for the rules to apply.

Comment: You are right. "AND" this is rule for both scale (height and width), because in some cases we need exactly such rule. Because you can have two devices for example 320x560 and 320x480 and device rotation will broke you make up. I mean "comma" and "AND" sign is have different means.

Answer (score 303):

**The quick answer**

Separate rules with commas

`@media handheld, (min-width: 650px), (orientation: landscape)  { ... }`

---

**The long answer**

There's a lot here, but I've tried to make it information dense, not just fluffy writing. It's been a good chance to learn myself! *Take the time to systematically read though and I hope it will be helpful.*

### CSS Media Queries & Logical Operators: A Brief Overview ;)

**Media queries essentially are used in web design to create device- or situation-specific browsing experiences; this is done using the `@media` declaration within a page's [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Css).** This can be used to display a webpage differently under a large number of circumstances: whether you are on a tablet or TV with different aspect ratios, whether your device has a color or black-and-white screen, or, perhaps most frequently, when a user changes the size of their browser or switches between browsing devices with varying screen sizes (very generally speaking, designing like this is referred to as [Responsive Web Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design))

### Logical Operators

In designing for these situations, there appear to be ***four Logical Operators*** that can be used to require more complex combinations of requirements when targeting a variety of devices or [viewport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewport#Computing) sizes.

*(Note: If you don't understand the the differences between media rules, media queries, and feature queries, browse the bottom section of this answer first to get a bit better acquainted with the terminology associated with media query syntax*

**1. AND (*and* keyword)**

Requires that **all conditions specified must be met** before the styling rules will take effect.

`@media screen and (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }`

The specified styling rules won't go into place unless *all* of the following evaluate as true:

- The media type is 'screen' *and*
- The viewport is at least 700px wide *and*
- Screen orientation is currently landscape.

Note: I believe that used together, these three *feature queries* make up a single *media query*.

**2. OR (*Comma-separated lists*)**

Rather than an *or* keyword, comma-separated lists are used in chaining multiple media queries together to form a more complex media rule

`@media handheld, (min-width: 650px), (orientation: landscape) { ... }`

The specified styling **rules will go into effect once *any one* media query evaluates as true**:

1. The media type is 'handheld' *or*
2. The viewport is at least 650px wide *or*
3. Screen orientation is currently landscape.

**3. NOT (*not* keyword)**

The *not* keyword can be **used to negate a single *media query*** (and NOT a full media *rule*--meaning that it only negates entries between a set of commas and not the full media rule following the @media declaration).

Similarly, [note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#not) that the *not* keyword negates media queries, it *cannot* be used to negate an individual feature query within a media query.*

`@media not screen and (min-resolution: 300dpi), (min-width: 800px) { ... }`

The styling specified here will go into effect if

1. The media type AND min-resolution *don't both* meet their requirements ('screen' and '300dpi' respectively) *or*
2. The viewport is at least 800 pixels wide.

In other words, if the media type is 'screen' and the min-resolution is 300 dpi, the rule will *not* go into effect unless the min-width of the viewport is at least 800 pixels.

(The not keyword can be a little funky to state. Let me know if I can do better. ;)

**4. ONLY (*only* keyword)**

As I understand it, the *only* keyword is **used to prevent older browsers from misinterpreting newer media queries** as the earlier-used, narrower media type. When used correctly, older/non-compliant browsers should just ignore the styling altogether.

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (color)" href="example.css" />`

An older / non-compliant browser would just ignore this line of code altogether, I believe as it would read the *only* keyword and consider it an incorrect media *type*. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9286360/1963978) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8549529/1963978) for more info from smarter people)

**FOR MORE INFO**

For more info (including more features that can be queried), see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#Logical_operators

---

### Understanding Media Query Terminology

Note: I needed to learn the following terminology for everything here to make sense, particularly concerning the *not* keyword. Here it is as I understand it:

A **media *rule*** (MDN also seems to call these media statements) includes the term `@media` with all of its ensuing media queries

`@media all and (min-width: 800px)`

`@media only screen and (max-resolution:800dpi), not print`

`@media screen and (min-width: 700px), (orientation: landscape)`

`@media handheld, (min-width: 650px), (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1)`

A **media *query*** is a set of feature queries. They can be as simple as one feature query or they can use the *and* keyword to form a more complex query. Media queries can be comma-separated to form more complex media rules (see the *or* keyword above).

`screen` (Note: Only one feature query in use here.)

`only screen`

`only screen and (max-resolution:800dpi)`

`only tv and (device-aspect-ratio: 16/9) and (color)`

NOT `handheld, (min-width: 650px)`. (Note the comma: there are two media queries here.)

A **feature *query*** is the most basic portion of a media rule and simply concerns a given feature and its status in a given browsing situation.

`screen`

`(min-width: 650px)`

`(orientation: landscape)`

`(device-aspect-ratio: 16/9)`

---

Code snippets and information derived from:

[CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) by [Mozilla Contributors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries$history?page=1) (licensed under [CC-BY-SA 2.5](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/)). Some code samples were used with minor alterations to (hopefully) increase clarity of explanation.

Comment: Great answer however it could be improved with a preface that immediately provides the requisite answer ("max-width OR max-height") as concisely as possible (see fcalderans answer). The elaborate supporting context should then follow. Many users expect an instant solution without having to invest in a broader learning curve than necessary. As a user, I'd prefer to find an instant answer with _the option to pursue_ additional context rather than having to sift through the additional context _to find_ the answer. Irrespective, good work and formatting.

Comment: While this is a good write-up, I'm not so sure a specific question is a good place for an entire Media Queries primer. Or to put it conversely, the question is so specific as to not do this answer justice. Also, the term "feature query" doesn't appear in Media Queries, it appears in a [different CSS spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#at-supports), and using the term in the context of media queries is confusing - but I should tell that to whomever started using that term in the MDN article in the first place. The correct term as of Media Queries 4 is "media condition".

Comment: Lets say I have to support all iPhone devices, so should I write media queries for each device separately e.g iPhone 5 (both portrait&landscape),iPhone6, iPhone 6 Plus and so on.If yes, I will end up writing more media queries covering all size of devices. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways for writing a proper media queries in css. If you are writing media queries for larger device first, then the correct way of writing will be:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 415px){
    /* Styles */
}

@media only screen 
and (min-width : 769px){
    /* Styles */
}

@media only screen 
and (min-width : 992px){
    /* Styles */
}
```

But if you are writing media queries for smaller device first, then it would be something like:

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 991px){
    /* Styles */
}

@media only screen 
and (max-width : 768px){
    /* Styles */
}

@media only screen 
and (max-width : 414px){
    /* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, using `and`, like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px), 
       screen and (max-height: 600px) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer, which has +1000 upvotes