# media queries syntax

Tags: css, media-queries

I know its quite easy topic, but I found the syntax provided on w3.com is quite complex. Can anyone decode it? Is it important to understand it?

[Syntax here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#syntax):

```
media_query_list
 : S* [media_query [ ',' S* media_query ]* ]?
 ;
media_query
 : [ONLY | NOT]? S* media_type S* [ AND S* expression ]*
 | expression [ AND S* expression ]*
 ;
media_type
 : IDENT
 ;
expression
 : '(' S* media_feature S* [ ':' S* expr ]? ')' S*
 ;
media_feature
 : IDENT
 ;
```

It also specifies some tokens below it. Can anyone please decode them also.

Comment: Try finding some tutorials online.  If you have a specific technical question then rewrite the post.

Comment: No, it's not important to understand it. It's the grammar; it's not meant to be very human-readable. If you want to understand the syntax, read the rest of the spec, not the grammar.

Comment: tutorials go on explaining using examples and are easy understand and readable
this syntax is actually a W3C recommendation for standard
will still like to understand whats *S and IDENT

since the standard also says "Unknown media types are distinct from media types that do not actually match the IDENT production. Those fall under the malformed media query clause."

Comment: `S*` means any amount of whitespace and `IDENT` is an identifier. There isn't much more to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a formal [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) definition of the syntax. If you're looking for easy-to-read examples, have a look at [chapter 2 of the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0).

In short, `S` stands for a space character, `IDENT` for an identifier (like `foobar2`), `*` for zero or more repetitions. Let's go through it in detail:

```
media_query_list
 : S* [media_query [ ',' S* media_query ]* ]?
 ;
```

means that a `media_query_list` (that's the everything that can be in `@media ( here )`) consists of one or more `media_query`, separated by comma and optional spacing. For example, these are valid `media_query_list`s:

```
media_query
 media_query,  media_query,   media_query,media_query
```

The definition of `media_query` is given later, in

```
media_query
 : [ONLY | NOT]? S* media_type S* [ AND S* expression ]*
 | expression [ AND S* expression ]*
```

The `|` means there are two forms. Either one of

```
 media_type
 ONLY media_type
 NOT media_type
```

(and optional expressions, joined with `AND`), *or* just an expression followed by optional multiple other expressions, joined with `AND`.

An expression is defined as follows:

```
expression
 : '(' S* media_feature S* [ ':' S* expr ]? ')' S*
```

That means it's always in parentheses, and consists of either just a `media_feature`, or a media feature followed by an `expr`. For example, these are valid expressions:

```
(foo)
(foo: 2px)
```

In this definition, `media_type` and `media_feature` can be arbitrary identifiers. In practice, they will be identifiers that are recognized by the browsers, like `print`, `screen`, `max-width` etc..

Comment: Arbitrary identifiers are still parsed whether they are recognized or not; they'll be resolved as `unknown` if they are not recognized. But that's just a little tidbit and nothing important...

Answer (score 0):

**For those who might be confused by the above syntax**, check out my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23524569/1963978) for a less techincal explanation of Media Query syntax as I understand it. It's too long to meaningfully repost here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23524569/1963978