# How do I force scroll bars in a fully responsive site?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I am currently helping a friend with a very simple, responsive 1-page site which can be viewed [here](http://www.vineinteractive.com).

If you drag your browser window down to about 450px in width or less, you will see that the layout changes which is correct.  However, when you drag vertically to make the page shorter, the content in the middle gets hidden/covered.

I need for the text in the middle to always be visible, even if the user needs to scroll/swipe to see it.  **NOTE**: It is the whole body that I would want to scroll, not just the content div.

In this image, you can see that the text is covered if the viewport isn't very tall:

[image]

On the div that contains the main content, I have tried setting height and min-height as well as using `!important` to no avail.

I must be missing something obvious.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd think about using a media query for viewport height; consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404744/media-queries-max-width-or-max-height), for example. Also, "stategic"?

Comment: I'd also note that, in Firefox 17 ESR, the content overlies the bottom bar rather than being hidden behind it; you may wish to consider explicit z-index specifications in your CSS to prevent this.

Comment: @AaronMiller--Thanks, the z-index problem should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Set the div named "content" the style: "overflow-y: scroll;"

```
<div id="content" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
<!-- content -->
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried this on my chrome browser and it worked fine, you should try.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Updated to be the whole document.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have been more clear.  I want the whole body to scroll, not just the content div.  I will edit my question.

Comment: updated my answer please add below or modify any other body specific css.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but this does not solve the problem of maintaining a consistent height in the content box.  If I use your suggestion, the content div still collapses when I make the window shorter.  I need for that content div to maintain a given `min-height` which would then force the scroll bar for the browser window on it's own.