# Media Queries: check min-height and min-width?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to change CSS on my page based on the min-height and min-width of the browser, so I am using this:

```css
@media (min-height: 500px), (min-width: 580px) {
   /* CSS stuff */
}
```

But for some reason, this doesn't work. I can check for min-height and max-width (or vice versa) or for max-height and max-width at the same time, but checking for both min values doesn't seem to work.

I should specify this more: I want the browser to act if a min-height **or** a min-width becomes true. Using the and-operator will only work if both criteria are true.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The comma in media queries is just like a comma in selectors:  `.foo, .bar { color: red }`

Comment: @cimmanon the Mozilla guide specifies this: "Comma-separated lists behave like the logical operator or when used in media queries."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS media queries: max-width OR max-height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404744/css-media-queries-max-width-or-max-height)

Comment: it was almost 4 years ago, but only a year before this question, there was the same one... answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11404776/3279496

Answer (score 89):

Use `and` instead of a comma, like this:

```css
@media (min-height: 500px) and (min-width: 580px) {
    /* CSS stuff */
}
```

Comment: Using the and operator will actually only activate the CSS stuff if both requirements are true, so if the browser height is below 500px and the width is below 580px. I want to activate it if any of the two cases are true.

Answer (score 10):

Have you added following meta tag in  :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Here is REf : http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag/

After that use your media Query :

```
@media (min-height: 500px) and (min-width: 580px) {
    /* CSS stuff */
}
```

For media query details you can more info from http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/ for all iOS devices. If you have any other query let me know. Even you can get better idea from here http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps

Comment: I actually had the viewport meta tag already included and as I said, it works for max+max and min+max, but not for min+min.

Answer (score 10):

Use media query one inside other:

```
@media  screen and  (min-height: 40px)  {
   @media  screen and  (min-width: 50px)  {
    /*enter css here to apply for both condition*/
   }
}
```

Comment: Nested media queries is still not fully supported as of January 2015, it has problems in IE and Safari.