# Add media query only to specific device ipad pro

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want to add media query to specific device ipad pro of size 1366*1024 height width and height.How do i add media query to to that size targeting only that width and height.Not less than 1366 or greater than 1366 !!!

Comment: Please add codes of what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy pasted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837035/media-queries-check-min-height-and-min-width)

```
@media (min-height: 1024px) and (min-width: 1366px) {
    /* CSS stuff */
}
```

Don't forget `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` meta tag on header too.

Comment: `@media (min-height: 1024px) and (min-width: 1366px) and (max-height: 1024px) {
    /* CSS stuff */
}`

Taken from - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Logical_operators

Use the logical operators to your craft.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 1024px) 
and (max-device-width : 1366px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

Reference [link](https://identifywebdesign.co.uk/css-media-queries-for-the-ipad-pro/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 1024px) 
      and (max-device-width: 1366px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
  //code
    }
```

You can also specify if you want to set over portrait or landscape:

```
    /* Portrait */
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 1024px) 
      and (max-device-width: 1366px) 
      and (orientation: portrait) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
  //code
    }

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1366px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
//code
}
```