# Breakpoint on Width OR Height

Tags: breakpoint-sass

I recently found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11404776/2525706) answer on SO, and was wondering if there is a syntax to accomplish this with breakpoint-sass plugin?  Thanks.

EDIT (since there was confusion):

Have a breakpoint dependent on height and width, similar to this media query from the posted question.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 995px) , screen and (max-height: 700px) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: This question wound up in the low quality review queue.  I think it would be OK if edited to include a snippet and explain what you mean by "accomplish this" because readers are kind of expecting that upfront even though the other SO question is fairly short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breakpoint allows for media breakpoint and or breakpoints, so constructing this MQ is fairly straight forward:

http://sassmeister.com/gist/3b7127ded8e032d90f4d