# What is the difference between using or not the word all in media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

What is the difference between this two:

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait){}
@media(orientation:portrait){}
```

I always thought that by default media queries affected all medias, therefore there is no need for that all, but I see that so frequently lately that I'm not sure any more.

Is there really a difference?

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404744/media-queries-max-width-or-max-height with details about CSS Media Queries & Logical Operators

Comment: @user1162084: all is not a logical operator. You may be confusing it with and.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation says](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0):

> A shorthand syntax is offered for media queries that apply to all media types; the keyword ‘all’ can be left out (along with the trailing ‘and’). I.e. if the media type is not explicitly given it is ‘all’.

I.e. these are identical:

```
@media all and (min-width:500px) { … }
@media (min-width:500px) { … }
```

As are these:

```
@media (orientation: portrait) { … }
@media all and (orientation: portrait) { … }
```

Comment: why is people using it a lot, then? They just love to make their css longer or what?

Comment: Well, idk really, maybe they don't know that there is a shorter version. I always use [Bootstraps media querys](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1585), which are also in the shorther version.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference, feels like just an artefact from the spec authors, left there maybe so that the code can be more intuitive.