# Media query not working with height

Tags: css, media-queries

This is my media query for resolution with width of 1280 pixels:

```
@media (min-width: 1270px) and (max-width: 1280px)
```

When I want to use seperate query for height like this:

```
@media (min-width: 1270px) and (max-height: 960px)
```

It doesn't work. It's not showing even in the developer tools in chrome. Can I get some suggestions?

Comment: Is your browser the right height?

Comment: i think you need to separate out the height/width portions with a comma, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404744/media-queries-max-width-or-max-height

Comment: It doesn't work with commas..

Comment: show me how you wrote it with a comma.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad `@media screen and (min-width: 1270px), screen and (max-height: 960px )`

Comment: try adding a space before the comma too

Comment: Not working. It's still uses `@media (max-width: 1280px) and (min-width: 1270px)` and not `@media screen and (min-width: 1270px), screen and (max-height: 960px )`

Comment: hmm.. sounds like a cache problem. try clearing out your cache and refreshing the page

Comment: Media queries work in the format you specified. The problem must be something else. Example here: http://codepen.io/marceloa/pen/QyzRGY?editors=1100

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/fxaknLn7/ it works here see

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a comma between different conditions (width/height)

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1270px), screen and (max-height: 960px )
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/fxaknLn7/

Comment: It would be good now, but now it's shows that at first uses `@media (max-width: 1280px) and (min-width: 1270px)` and just then the one with `height`

Comment: there's another problem then. are you referencing multiple css files? do they have different media queries? check all these things. did you try clearing your browser's cache? refresh page after. etc

Comment: I'm using only one .css It just shows this: `@media (min-width: 1270px) and (max-width: 1280px )` and then `@media (min-width: 1270px) and (max-height: 960px )` this

Comment: did you clear your browser cache? go to settings -> history -> clear all browsing data

Comment: Yes. I think I have a problem with res. There were before the same things happened and I manage to fixed them, probably I should try another options

Answer (score -1):

You must add this code at first

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

and use this link

https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 995px) , screen and (max-height: 700px) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: i don't think he needs that

Comment: I have it. Media query's just doesnt work with heights

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404744/media-queries-max-width-or-max-height