# Hide the Background Image on Browser resize

Tags: css, background-image

Is There any way in CSS to Hide the Background Image from top when i resize the browser by changing the height and Hide the Background Image from right when i resize the browser by changing the width without the image gets shrink. Im able to achieve only hiding from right on maximum height. If I tried to resize on both sides the image gets shrink and not hided. Below is my CSS code.

```
 body {
  background-image:url("");
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:bottom left;
}
```

I want to hide the background image from top and right when I resize from any direction and for any width and height. Can someone plz help.

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404744/media-queries-max-width-or-max-height

Comment: Yes i tried using above code inside media queries. But it doesn't work on cutting the image on top and right, instead it gets shrink.

Answer (score 0):

please check this for a try

```css
@media (max-width:1200px){
  body { background:none !important; }
}
```