# CSS if else conditions, mobile portrait or landscape

Tags: css, media-queries, orientation

How to use a with-height conditions. Without javascript.

```
@media (calc(window-width > window-height)) {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
@media (calc(window-width <= window-height)) {
    background-color: lightgray;                
}
```

I want to page for mobile defices for detecting if mobile is rotated to portrait or landscape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`orientation` constraint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation):

```
@media (orientation: landscape) {
    /* applies to devices in landscape mode */
}
@media (orientation: portrait) {
    /* applies to devices in portrait mode */
}
```

Multiple rules are comma separated (`OR`), otherwise use `AND`.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: Can somebody say how to put to work in Safary browser a css code like:

Comment: @media (min-width: 150vh) {
 .imageMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 150vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
 }
}

Comment: @media (max-width: 150vh) {
 .imageMap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 66vw;
  background-color: lightgray;
 }
}

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
.something {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

@media (orientation: landscape) { 
    .something {
        background-color: lightgray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use media queries with `height` also -

For example -

```
@media screen and (max-width: 995px) , screen and (max-height: 700px) {
  ...
}
```

or you can use with *orientation*

```
@media (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

And you can also use  with height

```
@media (max-height: 700px), handheld and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

Some of my friend also post the MDN URL you can get more information from that.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404744/media-queries-max-width-or-max-height) can be useful for you

Answer (score 2):

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#orientation):

> **orientation**
>
> *Value: landscape | portrait*
>
> *Media: visual*
>
> *Accepts min/max prefixes: no*
>
> Indicates whether the viewport is in landscape (the display is wider
>   than it is tall) or portrait (the display is taller than it is wide)
>   mode.
>
> **Example**
>
> To apply a style sheet only in portrait orientation:
>
> `@media all and (orientation: portrait) { ... }`
>
> **Note:** This value does
>   not correspond to actual device orientation. Opening the soft keyboard
>   on most devices in portrait orientation will cause the viewport to
>   become wider than it is tall, thereby causing the browser to use
>   landscape styles instead of portrait.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use calc method as the calc method is css property's value not property.

But you can combine media rule with max-width and min-width (paste the width or height value instead xxx):

```
@media(max-width:xxx) and (min-width: xxx){}
@media(min-width:xxx) and (max-height: xxx){}
```

You can also use more advanced media query like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: xxx) and (min-width: xxx), (min-width: xxx) {}
```

If you're trying to work with portrait and landscape, then you can do like this:

```
/* Portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* Portrait styles */
}
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* Landscape styles */
}
```

Refer this [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) that's all we have.