# CSS media queries: max-width And max-height

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I want to use AND condition in media query. I use the the following code,  but it didn't works

```
@media screen and (max-width: 995px AND max-height: 700px) {
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS media queries: max-width OR max-height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404744/css-media-queries-max-width-or-max-height)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's missing close and open parenthesis before and after the Logical Operator

```
@media (max-width: 995px) and (max-height: 700px) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct and simpliest way to write this is:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 995px) and (max-height: 700px) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a comma to specify two (or more) different rules:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 995px) , screen and (max-height: 700px) {
 ...
}
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries/

...In addition, you can combine multiple media queries in a comma-separated list; if any of the media queries in the list is true, the associated style sheet is applied. This is the equivalent of a logical "or" operation.