# Hero Image with min-height: 100vh too large

Tags: html, css

I am using min-height: 100vh on a hero image, but I am noticing on lg-xl screens the image becomes extremely large. Is there a way to correct this or cap the height of the hero image without affecting the overlay within the image. **Please note there is an overlay on top of the image so using height 100vh doesn't work**
My code is as follows:

```
<div className="bg-img"></div>
```

```
.bg-img {
min-height: 100vh;
background-image: url('https://storage.googleapis.com/youfit-assets/nologo.png');
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS media queries: max-width OR max-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404744/css-media-queries-max-width-or-max-height)

Comment: ???? no it doesn't

Comment: How does it not? On large screens just use a media query to cap the height. Can you create a fiddle of the issue so we can help you better?

Answer (score 0):

> Try doing `height: 100vh;` instead of `min-height: 100vh;`. Maybe that is what is bugging you.

And then I tested it and saw that the attribute `className` is invalid and should be `class`.

Comment: using react.... className is used in react

Comment: and height 100vh cuts off the overlay on top of the image

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  
 }
 body{
 min-height: 100vh;
 }
.bg-img{
 height: 100vh;
}
```

This will probably work in your case

Comment: this won't work as there is an overlay on top of the image.  I provided a simple example of my usecase

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).